# When I want to import AppCompatActivity it says it cannot resolved?

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

When I want to import appcompatActivity it says it cannot resolved but i have sync my gradle and it had been successful , what is the problem ?
the version is :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to import, exactly? The correct class name is `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @MikeM. its this : 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, `AppCompatActivity` wasn't introduced until [version 22.1.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html#rev22-1-0) of the support library. You're using version 21.0.3. Try upgrading.